# Unable to achieve desired effect with Masonry layout

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-masonry, masonry

I am really stumped here. Since this is a layout question , you will need to look at my [codepen example](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/jAwRqp).

basically, if you see on the second row, there is a giant space between the two blocks. Why? Why doesn't it line up?

This is the options for masonry:

```
$('.grid').masonry({
  itemSelector: '.grid-item',
  columnWidth: '.grid-sizer',
  percentPosition: true
});
```

Also, fiddle with the width of the third grid-item. Ideally, i want it to be 50% and all my divs will fit together in the space, packed tightly. The reason I have the custom width on it is that 40% is the max width before it moves it to the next row. WHY? It needs to be on the same row. 50% + 50% = 100% so there is room. Why do you think its broken?

1) JQuery Plugin https://github.com/desandro/masonry

Answer (score 0):

The space is there because the columnWidth is 20%, but the first item is 50%. a 50% item is rounded up to 60%. So there's 10% extra space.

But if you change .grid-sizer { width: 10%; } that will allow 50% item to be measured at 50%.